# How to model many to many relation in Cassandra 3.0 with performance in mind

Tags: algorithm, performance, database-design, cassandra

I am trying to define the cassandra tables for the following problem.
I have the following relations:
A user (user_id) can see many adds (add_id).
A add (add_id) can be saw by more that one user.

And I want to make the following querys in cassandra:

1. Given a user (user_id) give me all the adds (add_id) that the user saw
2. Given a add (add_id) give me all the users (user_id) that saw that add

The aproach I took was to create two tables whith the relations

```
CREATE TABLE adds_by_user (
    user_id text,
    add_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, add_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_by_add (
    add_id text,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (add_id, user_id)
);
```

My algorithm do the following
Given a **user_id**:

1. Give me all the **add_id** that the user watched.
2. **for each add_id**, give me all the **user_id** that watched that **add_id**
3. **for each user_id**, give me all the **add_id** that each user watched

Another graphical way to see it is:

(one) user_id -> (many) add_id -> (many+) user_id -> (many++) add_id

The problems arises when I have a lot of relations and the algorithm spends a lot of time doing all the queries (despite the fact that each individual query is done in 0.5 milliseconds or less, **but there are a lot of them**)

I am already using async queries

**Is there a model that I can make the queries faster?**

**Is there a model that will make the algorithm make less queries and respect Cassandra standards?**

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to fit a node/graph database structure like neo4j, into cassandra. There is good way to resolve this.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekAnand sory that I don' t undestand your response, you are saying that there is a good way to resolve this in cassandra or you are saying that I have to use neoj4 for this model?

Answer (score 1):

Example of data model:

```
CREATE TABLE user_address_user(
    user_id text,
    address_id text,
    user_level2 text,
    address_level2 text, 
    PRIMARY KEY((user_id), address_id, user_level2, address_level2)
);
```

This table structure can be seen as

`Map<user_id, SortedMap<address_id, SortedMap<user_level2, SortedSet<address_level2>>>>`

Comment: Hi @doanduyhai, I think the solution you propose is if I spend too much time writting the relations, but the problem I have is not in the **write time**, the problem is in the **read time**.